# How to round decimals like this?

Tags: php, math, rounding, smarty3

I want to round decimals, my code is working but i would like to get output like this.

sample

```
49.155
49.555
49.955
```

Tried with {$var|round:0}

Output giving

```
49
50
50
```

looking output

```
49
49
49
```

Answer (score 0):

Use math floor function. It will give you the lowest decimal number (for positive numbers).

```
import math
math.floor(x)
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty the syntax is

```
{$var|floor}
```